# What is the proper way of accessing a public post from a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a CMS application which needs a little component that allows an editor to select a facebook page post to display.

I've been going around facebook API and I don't fully understand what is the proper way of doing it.

This would be a server call, I would prefer not to have an access token because I am not making the request on behalf of any user.

I've tried using access_token=app_id|app_secret, but apparently that request requires an user session. So I went to the graph explorer and copied my access token. That worked fine initially but then I learned that they expire. I could get a long live token, but apparently those also expire eventually.

So, what is the best way of doing this? I think that using someones facebook access token for this is risky. The token could be revoked at any point breaking the feature in production. Can I achieve this without an user access_token? if I cant, how is this token normally managed?

Update:
Well actually the app_id|app_secret works, just not in every case. I created several pages for testing purposes and it doesnt work in any of them. Then I tried accessing a post from some brand pages (unrelated to my project) and they work ok. So my problem is configuring the page.
When I tried to access the post using app_id|app_secret I get:

```
(#100) Requires user session
```

- Posts are public in all cases
- I already tried to assign a vanity url to the page, no change

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to use just an App Access Token to get the Page Posts. Unfortunately the docs are not very clear on this IMHO:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/#readperms

> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.